# Display a row of data in columns in C#

Tags: c#

I have a list of data that I have calculated (all in C#)

I want to display the result of the calculated data in 4 columns instead of one long row.

This is what I have in my prompt right now:

```
1
2
3
4 etc
```

This is what I want:

```
1     2     3     4  
5     6     7     8  etc
```

How can I do that in C#?

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private static void Print(int[] arr)
{
    int counter = 0;
    
    foreach (int item in arr)
    {
        if (counter == 4) // can be configured to desired columns
        {
            counter = 0;
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        counter++;
        Console.Write(item + " ");
    }
}
```

INPUT: `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13}`

OUTPUT:

```
1 2 3 4 

5 6 7 8

9 10 11 12

13
```

Demo Fiddler: [Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/s7qt8K)

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)